# How to set async: true in .load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code hangs Chrome and Safari for about 3sec. Firefox works perfectly. How can i set this in  async: true -state? Or is my only option preload all pages in divs and hide them when entering to site?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Button").click(function(evt) {
$('#change').html('<p><img src="ajax-loader.gif" width="15" height="15" /></p>');
 $("#change").load('reg.php')
    })    
});
```

Comment: .load is async: true by default. If you set async: false globally, the only way to change would be to set it to true globally, or to use $.ajax instead.

Comment: Check the jQuery Manual: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6685294/2493918).

Comment: I have changed to this but it still hangs?

$.ajaxSetup({

  async: true
});

$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#Button").click(function(evt) {
 $('#vaihtuva').html('<p><img src="ajax-loader.gif" width="15" height="15" /></p>');

  $.ajax({
  url: "reg.php",
  cache: false,
  async: true
}).done(function( html ) {
  $("#change").html(html);
})
})
});