# ajax json synchronous not working with async set to false

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, synchronous

synchronous ajax is not working:

```
        var rslt = false;

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {                      
                     rslt = true;                      
                }                      
                });


            document.write(rslt);
```

rslt still displays as false.

I am out of ideas...

Comment: Maybe you're getting an ERROR. You don't have any error detection here

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Performing synchronous AJAX requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests)

Comment: if you weren't using `document.write`, you wouldn't feel the need to use synchronous AJAX. The disease is bad, but so is the cure.

Comment: i don't think you should get callbacks with sync...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could inform if it's a GET or a POST, as you're not passing anything, I think its a get, sou set the type to 'GET'

This should work:

```
var rslt = false;

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: url,
                success: function(data) {                      
                     rslt = true;                      
                }                      
            });


document.write(rslt);
```

Comment: `contentType` specifies the format of the data that is *sent to the server*.

Comment: try adding into your ajax: error: function (request) { alert(request); }