# get the value of variable exist inside the ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to validate email, what's wrong in this.
Return false is not working

```
$.validator.addMethod("email_exist", function(value, element, arg){
    var x = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../signup/validateemail.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'email_address='+value,
        cache:false,
        success: function(response) { 
            if(response == 0){
                x++;
            }
        }
    });
    alert(x);
    if(x > 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        alert('yeh');
        return true;
    }
    return true;
 },'');
```

Comment: because ajax is asynch request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wont return false as the ajax method is asynchronous, it will not wait for the success event to happen. You can make the ajax synchronous by making

```
async: false
```

but it is not a good method. It will freeze the browser as well

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 1):

You do **asynk** call.So in you case,first execute alert(x),then code in success function.
You can do this request synk (async: false) or change code in success