# Why can't I capture a variable inside a get call?

Tags: ajax

This is my code:

```
var user_ip ="not found";

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
   var user_ip=response.ip; 
   alert("on line 749 user ip is " + user_ip);
}, "jsonp");
alert("on line 751 user ip is " + user_ip);
```

Yet my user ip only get saved within the .get, afterwards it always reverts to "not found".

I know this involves using a call back to save the data but cant find an example of how to do it that makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

That's because the callback is executed asynchronously, way after

```
alert("on line 751 user ip is " + user_ip);
```

has been executed.

You could do a synchronous GET request as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests) but I consider synchronous code as bad practice :)

A second problem is that you redeclare `user_ip` inside the scope of the callback function, which means that the global `user_ip` will not be overridden as you might have intended.

Comment: Hi, if you consider synchronous code as bad practice what is a solution then?  not declaring user_ip beforehand doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: well, you get the user_ip in the callback, so you have what you want :) What do you want to do with the ip afterwards?

Comment: I want to use it as a variable for a string that I need later in the script  .

Comment: make your code asynchronous and all your problems will disappear. Check out [`$.Deferred`](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/) and read about promises.

Comment: If you tell me _what_ you'll do with `user_ip` I could give you a concrete example.

Comment: I want to send the ip number along with other variables to google analytics.  but I want to send it to google analytics even if the call to get the ip fails.

Comment: Then use `done` and `fail` functions: `$.get(...).done(function (ip){sendToAnalytics}).fail(function(){sendToAnalytics});`