# How can i return something what callback function fetches

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

I have an ajax library You can see the code [here](http://github.com/nikosEfthias/easyAjax).
I have another function what uses ajax function and needs to return what ajax function returns simply something like this

```
function returnMyData(){
var data;
    ajax.get("someDomain",function(err,dt){
    if(dt){data= dt}
    });
return data;
}
```

Here everything looks fine but javascript will return null because callback wont fetch the data yet due to multi thread nature of  javascript.
So my question how can i wait till data is fetched and return then  i tried to use while but it freezes the browser or gives unresponsive script error.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests

Comment: if you just a bit check the code you will see there is nothing about jquery and i wanna use async code as sync @SebastianNette its not just ajax based and check my ajax library as well