# jQuery access variable outside each loop

Tags: jquery

I need to access a var "cont" after each loop has run. I need to run an email if cont =  true which is set after an ajax call in each loop.
I've read that each loop is synchronous but when i console log var cont after each loop, i get false even though it is set as true.

```
$(".check").click(function (event) {
    var cont = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    $("form.form").each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.find('input.name').val();
        var company = $this.find('input.comp_name').val();
        var jtitle = $this.find('input.job_title').val();
        var link = $this.find('input.link').val();
        var email = $('input.email').val();

        if ((name === "") || (company === "") || (jtitle === "")) {
            $this.addClass("NotFilled");
        } else {
            var url = $this.attr('action');
            // fetch the data for the form
            var data = $this.serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: "post",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result === "success") {
                        cont = true;
                        $this.removeClass("NotFilled").addClass("filled");
                        //console.log(cont)  I Get True here
                    } else {
                        cont = false;
                        $this.removeClass("filled").addClass("NotFilled");
                    }
                    return cont;
                }

            });
        }
    });
    //console.log(cont)  I Get false here
    if (cont === "true") {
        $.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/x/x.php", {
            emailTo: email,
            emailFrom: 'x@x.co.uk',
            subject: 'New x x x',
            message: 'We x x x'
        },

               function (data) {});
    }
});
```

Comment: You've to put that code in the callback of  ajax call. because it;'s async in nature

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests

Answer (score 1):

The code inside your `each` method is ajax and it's async in nature.

So the statement

```
if(cont === "true"){
```

Will be executed even before the ajax calls succeeds/fails.

So you must either convert the ajax to be sync by setting the async flag or put the `if` condition inside the callback.

Example synchronous ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async: false

    type: "post",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result === "success") {
            cont = true;
            $this.removeClass("NotFilled").addClass("filled");
            //console.log(cont)  I Get True here
        } else {
            cont = false;
            $this.removeClass("filled").addClass("NotFilled");
        }
        return cont;
    }

});
```

Comment: Forcing async: false is bad practice and in some uses depricated

Comment: @jimmyjansen Ya, it's not recommended. But i'm just giving suggestions to make current code to work. The much better approach would be to use a promise and handle all the ajax requests to return a promise and when the promises resolves, trigger the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Since your call is asynchronous, the execution of the code will continue directly after the ajax call.

You can set `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});` to have your code wait for the execution of the ajax call and set `$.ajaxSetup({async: true});` after the execution.

Answer (score 0):

like @mohamedrias said: javascript is async from its very core. This means that your if statement is executed before the ajax call has returned a success or fail

consider the following code:

```js
console.log('First');
jQuery.get('page.html', function(data) {
  console.log("Second");
});
console.log('Third');
```

In this snippet your console will log: First, Third, Second.

Now if we were to make this to run async:

```js
console.log('First');
getPage("page.html, function(){
  console.log('Third');          
}


var getPage(url, callback) {
  jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
    console.log("Second ");
  }
  callback();
}
```

Now it logs: First, Second, Third

There are a lot of resources about this on the internet, the one I used to understand this is: [this one](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/)