# Why does this XMLHttpRequest return undefined?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Why does the following XMLHttpRequest return undefined?

```
function fetchFileList(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","../files.json",false);
    request.onload = function(){
        if(request.status == 200){
            return request.responseText;
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

, but if I console.log() `request.responseText`, the console outputs what it's supposed to:

```
if(request.status == 200){
            console.log(request.responseText);
            return request.responseText;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because `fetchFileList` does not return anything. It does not have a return statement. You probably want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Felix Kling ... Thanks, I didn't notice that. The anonymous function acutally reutrns the response text. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need a little course: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32163917/1636522.