# How to make a Auto add row select option with value take from database mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I had tried to enter the auto-add input regular, successful
but I am confused because the system displays the new line comes from javascript. Can I mix with php and mysql?

sorry for my bad english, and i'm a new user stackoverflow :(

i was try this and work

```html
<?php include 'load/masuk.php'; include 'load/anti_injection.php'; ?>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">
    <div id="dynamicInput">
      Entry 1
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 1;
  var limit = 3;

  function addInput(divName) {
    if (counter == limit) {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    } else { <? php
      $saring = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM perangkat");

      ?>
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
      counter++;
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

but when i try add new line for mix them with php and mysql like this

```html
<?php
include 'load/masuk.php';
include 'load/anti_injection.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var counter = 1;
 var limit = 3;
 function addInput(divName){
      if (counter == limit)  {
           alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
      }
      else {
       <?php
        $saring=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM perangkat");
        
       ?>
           var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
           newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
           newdiv.innerHTML = <?php echo"<select>"; while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($saring)) {echo "<option value='$data[id_perangkat]'>$data[id_nama]</option>"; echo"</select>";}?>
           document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
           counter++;
      }
 }
</script>
</html>
```

that doesn't work :(

I am less familiar with javascript, but I understand php and mysql

Comment: *"Can I mix with php and mysql?"* - No. You need to use Ajax for that.

Comment: ahh :( can you give me a tutorial ajax for this problem?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php - Then Google "php ajax" to further your research.

Comment: oh, thanks fred ! I will try to learn from the tutorial

Comment: If you don't know what Ajax is, the following post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32163917/1636522.