# javascript is getting executed in reverse order

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function duplicateCenter(center, email) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../staff/staffDA.php",
        data: "funId=-4&center=" + center + "&email=" + email,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.split('|')[0] === 'true') {
                alert('Duplicate Entry Found !!\r\n' + data.split('|')[1]);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

function addCenterInfo() {
   /* some coding and initializations */

    if (!duplicateCenter(center, email)) {
        return;
    }

    alert('hi');
    alert('hi');

    /* more codes */
}
```

Anyone please help me to understand, why is above function is getting executed in reverse order ?

Current order of execution is

```
`hi`
`hi`
`Duplicate Entry Found !!`
```

where as expected execution should only be `Duplicate Entry Found !!` and it should come out from the function.

Answer (score 2):

**duplicateCenter** contains **AJAX** code which is **Asynchronous**

*Anyone please help me to understand, why is above function is getting executed in reverse order ?*
**Code is working in correct Asynchronous order**

For more info about AJAX refer this answer:
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Possible Solution:
Use callback

```js
function duplicateCenter(center, email, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../staff/staffDA.php",
    data: "funId=-4&center=" + center + "&email=" + email,
    success: function(data) {
      var flag=false;
      if (data.split('|')[0] === 'true') {
        flag=true;
        alert('Duplicate Entry Found !!\r\n' + data.split('|')[1]);
      }
      if(typeof callback==='function') callback(flag);
    }
  });
}

function addCenterInfo() {
  /* some coding and initializations */
  duplicateCenter(center, email, function(isDuplicate) {
    if (isDuplicate) {
      alert('duplicate');
    } else {
      alert('not duplicate');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "A" in "Ajax" stands for "Asynchronous".  You are kicking off the duplicateCenter() function before the alerts, but that function then returns without waiting for the response.  By the time the call to staffDA.php completes, the alerts have already been executed.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls are Asynchronous. What this means is that you don't know when they will return. That is why you have to specify a `success` function in the first place: it only gets called when the AJAX call returns, which could be in less than a second or in many.

So, if you want to call code only after the `success` method has run, you need to make your code look like this:

```
function duplicateCenter(center, email) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../staff/staffDA.php",
        data: "funId=-4&center=" + center + "&email=" + email,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.split('|')[0] === 'true') {
                alert('Duplicate Entry Found !!\r\n' + data.split('|')[1]);
                itWasFalse();
            }
        }
    });
}

function itWasFalse() {
   // just en empty return? so lonely (and not needed - all JS functions return)
}

function moreCodes() {
    alert('hi');
    alert('hi');

    /* more codes */
}

function addCenterInfo() {
   /* some coding and initializations */
   duplicateCenter(center, email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function declaration, the order in which they will be executed rather depends from the invocation of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have added one extra line of code in my existing function i.e.

**async:false**

Now, it is working same as I expected.

```
function duplicateCenter(center, email) {
flag=true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../staff/staffDA.php",
        async:false,
        data: "funId=-4&center=" + center + "&email=" + email,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.split('|')[0] === 'true') {
                alert('Duplicate Entry Found !!\r\n' + data.split('|')[1]);
                flag=false;
            }else{
               flag=true;
            }

        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

**Reference : -**

[jQuery: Performing synchronous AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests)