# use get() inside each() in Jquery and perform action in client side itself

Tags: jquery, ajax, static, get, synchronous

I want to make this Ajax call using get() inside each() function to fetch data from the files, looping through the each().

this is my piece of code:

```
    jQuery.each(html_files, function(index,post_html){
        jQuery.get(post_html, function(data){
            // do action
        });
    });
```

here, html_files is an array, containing list of html files.

However, i am only able to fetch the data for the first file. 
How do i execute this synchronously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Performing synchronous AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests)

Comment: I Want to do the action in jQuery itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.each(html_files, function(index,post_html){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:get,
        url:post_html, //or the url to fetch data
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
         }
    });
});
```

Check this out

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me!