# Popup window when the page is closed

Tags: javascript, html, django

hello i have a Django base app and one of its apps is chatting with customer service.

i want when the customer clicks on the the [x] icon or close the window, a small popup window should come up that include:

1.a string like "thank you, and we hope you can take time and answer the survey:"
 2. a button that directs the customer to the survey page.

i have this part of the chatting app java script file:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       window.open ("http://gadgetron.store/male_chatbot/popup/"); <= i have tried it and it doesn't work
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://gadgetron.store/chatbot/run_python_clear_chatM/',});}
```

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I tried some thing like that before, but I think the browser disabled the popup customization. and note that you need configure the ajax call as synchronous (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests)). you can use **window.onunload** event handler, and then small popup with confirm and cancel button, if you click on confirm you script will be executed and the tab will closed

Answer (score 0):

For user experience reasons, browsers do not allow opening Popups during the unload-phase, which this event is part of. The only thing you can do is open a popup, asking the user to confirm that he really wants to leave the page. This is achieved by returning any non-empty string from the event callback (ie. `return "Are you sure you want to leave?";` where you currently call `window.open`). The text inside this confirmation window can no longer be influenced by the application [for most modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility).

For information regarding popups during the unload phase, have a look at the [WHATWG Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unloading-documents), most importantly the `ignore-opens-during-unload counter` which blocks `document.open` when set to any value greater than 0.