# why ajax sending request one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering today.

In my project ajax not making asynchronous call. request is sending one after another.

while processing one request, rest other all requests putting in pending.

you can see in below image
[image]

this happening from last night.

Comment: Could you provide us the code which sends the ajax requests?

Comment: Hope the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests help you out

Comment: function DelVideos(VideoID) {
    var param = { "VideoID": VideoID };
    param = JSON.stringify(param);
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/KnowledgeAreas/DelVideos",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: param,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#DelVideoModal').find('button.close').click();
            GetVideos();
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};

Comment: it normal ajax call only it was working up to last night.  i don't know what happen in my project .

Comment: requests are sending one after another

Comment: In your code you can see that `GetVideos()` gets called after the ajax call "DelVideos" is completed so it acts like synchronous requests.

Comment: How get insVideos, AddVideos and DelVideos called? After users clicks something or automatically through your code or something else?

Comment: after user click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not relevant how is applying Ajax calls. It is mostly relevant with ASP.NET is managing session. Here is the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

**Concurrent Requests and Session State**

> Access to ASP.NET session state
>   is exclusive per session, which means that if two different users make
>   concurrent requests, access to each separate session is granted
>   concurrently. However, if two concurrent requests are made for the
>   same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request
>   gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request
>   executes only after the first request is finished.

As you see, if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (so in your case it is) the second one applying after the first request is responsed.

**EDIT**

If you don't want that behaviour, you can decorate your controller with `SessionStateAttribute` and disable to access the session.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```

If you want to only read access to the session, you can add the attribute like this.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

Comment: thanks. your answer is related to my current problem.

Comment: i am using <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="360"/> this in my web.config file

Comment: can you please explain me in detail

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595097/ajax-post-request-with-xhr-stopping-all-author-requests

Comment: this is my another question