# Ajax post request with xhr stopping all author requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, amazon-s3

my requirement is upload files to server.
i using ajax call. 
when this ajax call starts remain all retests will goes on pending.

my code is:

```
function AddVideos(row, Video, CoverPhoto) {
    var param = { "ObjectFile": Video, "CoverPhoto": CoverPhoto, "VideoID": $(row).find('span.VidoID').text() };
    var Data = new FormData();
    $.each(param, function (key, element) {
        Data.append(key, element);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/KnowledgeAreas/AddVideos',
        data: Data,
        context: row,
        xhr: function () {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) { progress(event, row) }, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            GetVideos();
            $('#tblUploadingVideos tbody').find('span[name=' + $(row).find('span.VidoID').text() + ']').parents('tr').remove();
            if ($('#tblUploadingVideos tbody tr').length == 0) {
                $('#tblUploadingVideos').hide();
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
};
```

while processing this request. remain all requests will stop in queue.

you can see below .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by updating session state:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```