# Variables does not work as expected javascript - html

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables, null

So my problem is the next one:

I'm trying to get text from a JSON file, on my html on the header I linked a tag that has:

```
var language = "";
var langDoc = null;

//Function to change the value
function setLang() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("language");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        document.cookie = "language=español";
        language = "español";
        $.getJSON("/lenguajes/" + language + ".json", function(data) {
            langDoc = data;
        });
    }
    else {
        language = myCookie;
        $.getJSON("/lenguajes/" + language + ".json", function(data) {         
            langDoc = data;
        });
    }
}

//Final function to get text from file
function getTextFromJson(textToGet){
    return langDoc[textToGet];
}
```

And I'm trying to call the setLang(); function before calling my getTextFromJson() one, to get the text from the modified variable, but when I do it, the functions says that can't get the property "IDIOMA" from null, so the variable is not changing, the HTML looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> setLang(); </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert(getTextFromJson("IDIOMA")); </script>
<!-- other HTML  -->
```

And the idea is to be able to use that method on other parts of the HTML to make a multilanguage page

Thank you!

Comment: When are you calling the function? Try calling it from $.getJSON

Comment: I call setLang(); to get my document and my language and then I call getTextFromJson() and it should look on the document specified on setLang();, if I call it from the $.getJSON it works fine, but it is weird that my variable is not changed at all

Comment: $.getJSON is asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is an async method so the cause can be about the `JSON` is still not loaded when you are calling your `getTextFromJson` function so call this function from the success callback example is as follows:

```
var language = "";
var langDoc = null;

//Function to change the value
function setLang() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("language");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        document.cookie = "language=español";
        language = "español";
        $.getJSON("/lenguajes/" + language + ".json", function(data) {
            langDoc = data;
            getTextFromJson("");
        });
    }
    else {
        language = myCookie;
        $.getJSON("/lenguajes/" + language + ".json", function(data) {         
            langDoc = data;
             getTextFromJson("");
        });
    }
}

//Final function to get text from file
function getTextFromJson(textToGet){
    return langDoc[textToGet];
}
```

On the other case, you can also change your `$.getJSON` method to synchronous but this going to be deprecated soon. So try not using that. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests/6685294).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how did I not think about that! I'll try using ajax to make it syncronous. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> can't get the property "IDIOMA" from null

Looking at you code, looking at your code, we can tell rightly that `langDoc` has the initial value `null`

```
language = ""
langDoc = null
```

**The Point**

When `setLang()` is called from the Chrome browser console, this throws an error like this:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined
    at setLang (<anonymous>:6:20)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
setLang @ VM2043:6
(anonymous) @ VM2045:1
```

an error because `getCookie` is not defined, so `langDoc` remains `null`, and `getTextFromJson` returns error like this:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IDIOMA' of null
    at getTextFromJson (<anonymous>:25:19)
    at <anonymous>:1:7
```

**SOLUTION**
The `getCookie` function to fetch the cookie from the appropriate destination, so that this won't throw an error.

**EXAMPLE**

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous so it does not hold the `execution` and your `next script` is called before the `data` is returned from `JSON call`

Better way is to Handle with the `promises`.You can easily handle `error`, `success` cases.

Also there are some `code optimization` in your `if` and `else` condition

```
var language = "";
var langDoc = null;

//Function to change the value
function setLang() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("language");
    if (myCookie == null) {
        document.cookie = "language=español";
        language = "español";      
    }
    else {
        language = myCookie;      
    }
   var url= "/lenguajes/" + language + ".json";
   var myPromise = $.getJSON("url")
   myPromise.done(function(data) {
     //Handle the success case here
     langDoc=data;
   });

  myPromise.fail(function(reason) {
     //Handle the fail case here
   });
   //After success you can call your function 
   myPromise.then(function(data) {
     langDoc=data;
     getTextFromJson(data);
   });
}

//Final function to get text from file
function getTextFromJson(textToGet){
    return langDoc[textToGet];
}
```

Comment: thanks updated.....