# Unable to prevent form when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preventdefault

I am working on a form I wish to validate via jQuery $.ajax. The form should only be submitted if a certain condition, `data == 1`

```
var preventSubmit = function() {
  return false;
  var form = $(this),
    name = form.find('#name').val(),
    email = form.find('#email').val(),
    comment = form.find('#comment').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: absolute_store_link + '/ajax/comments-filter',
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      comment: comment
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // if data is equal to 1,
      // submit form
      if (data == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });

};

$("#comment_form").on('submit', preventSubmit);
```

The submit happens regardless if the condition is met or not.

Where is my mistake?

If I use `e.preventDefault();`, how can I "undo" it in case if data *is* equal to 1?

Comment: [Synchronous AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests).

Comment: @user202729 JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: i guess you know that the code after the `return` statement will never be executed?

Comment: @messerbill I want the default to be *do not submit*, bit if `(data == 1)` submit it.

Comment: but `return false` in the very first line of your function will always be the last line executed inside that function - code lines after a `return` statement are so called `unreachable code` because functions do not execute code behind the `return` keyword

Comment: @messerbill What is a viable alternative?

Comment: does the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to allow the submission of the form with a return value of true because the ajax is happening asynchronously (by the time it completes the function has already finished executing). What you *can* do is always prevent the form from submitting in the `preventSubmit` function, then submit it programmatically.

```js
var preventSubmit = function() {
  
  var form = $(this),
    name = form.find('#name').val(),
    email = form.find('#email').val(),
    comment = form.find('#comment').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: absolute_store_link + '/ajax/comments-filter',
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      comment: comment
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // if data is equal to 1,
      // submit form
      if (data == 1) {
        form.off();//remove bound events (this function)
        form.submit();//manually submit the form
      }
    }
  });
  return false;//the return needs to be at the end of the function and will always prevent submission
};

$("#comment_form").on('submit', preventSubmit);
```

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you included the `return false` at the end? That should definitely prevent form submission until the ajax resolves...

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the `return false;` will never be executed.

Also, you should be doing form validation on the front-end rather than the back-end. With that being said, you should not remove the validation from the back-end.

One more thing, try doing [HTML5 form validation](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/) first as that's your first line of defence.

You're looking at something on the lines of:

```
var validateForm = function(e) {
  // prevent the default form action to allow this code to run
  e.preventDefault();

  var isValid = false,
    form = $(this),
    name = form.find('#name').val(),
    email = form.find('#email').val(),
    comment = form.find('#comment').val();

  // Validation goes here
  // ...
  // isValid = true;

  if (isValid) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: absolute_store_link + '/ajax/comments-filter',
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        comment: comment
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // do something with the response. Maybe show a message?
        form.submit();
      }
    });
  }
};
```