# jQuery async ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that has a list, and for every element in this list, do an ajax call.

```
util.testMethod = function(list) {

            var map = new Map();

            list.forEach(function(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://......',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: // data needed here
                    success: function(data) {
                        // do something
                    },
                    error: function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                        // dos omething
                    }
                });
            });


            return map;
        };
```

Since I am making a number async ajax calls, let's assume there is 1 of them takes so long to execute. Is there a possibility that this testMethod will return before that ajax call finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely. The ajax call is asynchronous so the code will continue to execute without waiting for the success/error callback functions.

You have two options:

1. Make your ajax call as a synchronous call (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests))
2. *(recomended)* Make your `testMethod` functions an async function (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

**But** *(1º option)*:

> Setting async property to false is deprecated and in the process of
>   being removed ([link](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning)). Many browsers including Firefox and Chrome have
>   already started to print a warning in the console if you use this:

And follows an example for the 2º Option *(more about javascript promises in [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) and Promise.All in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all))*:

```js
async function makeAjaxCall()  {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Just to make the makeAjaxCall 1 second slower;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e6ac7d32d0000db0c5fa686',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {},
                success: function(data) {
                    resolve(data);
                },
                error: function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {

                     resolve({ error: 'OMG an ERROR!'});
                    // dos omething
                }
            })
        }, 1000);
    });      
};

async function asynCall() {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      // You can see in here that will wait 1 second before is going to the next ajax call
      const result = await makeAjaxCall();
      console.log(result);
  }
}

// You can run all your calls in paralel by using the Promise.All like this
async function promiseAll() {
  const ajaxCalls = [];
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      ajaxCalls.push(makeAjaxCall());
  }
  
  //for this case, the calls will be made in parallel, which measn will take slight more than 1 second 
  Promise.all(ajaxCalls).then(function(values) {
    // will print the array of values which contains the values of each ajax call
    console.log(values);
  });
}

asynCall();
promiseAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Option #1 is definitely not recommended and may not even be possible with modern browsers

Comment: Is there a way to force the function to wait for all ajax calls to finish before return?
It seems I can use something like $.when, but that only applies to a fix number of promises. But in my case, the number of promises will be the same as my list size.

Comment: @Haobo_X I made changes to my code. I hope such changes will answer to all your doubts.